# Magento 2.4 get value of Dynamic Rows for Ajax

Tags: magento2, javascript, dynamic-rows

I've got a form that uses ajax to submit data. I recently added a dynamicRows component to the form and using ajax doesn't appear to be as straight forward.

What I was using (on Non DynamicRows input)

```
let weight = $('input[name="registration_fieldset[weight]"]').val();//single input from Ui form
        let url = registrationUrl;

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {weight:weight},
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response.output);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response.output);
            }
        });
```

Getting the value of the DynamicRows element is not the same as a standard input such as:

```
$('input[name="registration_fieldset[attributes]"]').val();
```

How can I get the data from the DynamicRows element, in array/json format, with Javascript?

-- Update --
I've managed to get the data in the required format. The problem now is loading data retrieved from ajax into dynamic rows.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is Magento-related.

Comment: It is Magento related, yes. Isn't that the point of the Magento stackexchange?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `it is not Magento-related.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this using a custom jquery widget.

```
getDynamicRowsData: function () {
        let self = this;
        //rows is the table used to store the dynamic rows. 
        //data-index = the name of the dynamicRows element in the ui_components xml (<dynamicRows name="attributes" >)
        let rows = $("table[data-index='attributes']").find("tr");
        let data = [];
        rows.each(function(k, v){
            //input names
            let attrName = $("select[name='registration_fieldset[attributes][attributes][" + k + "][attribute_name]']").val();
            let attrVal = $("input[name='registration_fieldset[attributes][attributes][" + k + "][attribute_value]']").val();
            if (attrName && attrVal) {
                data.push(self.rowToObject(attrName, attrVal, k));
                data.push(self.rowToObject(attrName, attrVal, k));
            }
        });
        return data;
    },
    rowToObject: function (key, value, recordId) {
        //format so data displays correctly when loaded in the future
        const row = {};
        row.record_id = recordId;
        row.attribute_name = key;
        row.attribute_value = value;
        row['initialize'] = 'true';
        return row;
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try like this:

```
$('input[name="registration_fieldset[attributes]"]').on('click', function() { 
//or try on("change", func...)
// you may have to target the element that's being changed on "click/input" so that you can get the value
// and then call other (ajax) functions
    console.log($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. I'd like to get all of the data at once as if it was being submitted regularly.